# SHAP values cant compute shap explainer on SVM model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, shap

I am trying to compute shape explainer so i can visualize my model. However I keep getting the following error:

```
Exception: The passed model is not callable and cannot be analyzed directly with 
the given masker! Model: SVC(C=300, probability=True)
```

my code:

```
model =  create_model(SVC, C=300, probability=True) #user defined function works right
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

explainer = shap.Explainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)
 
shap.initjs()
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value,  X_train)
```

when I tried KernelExplainer along with X_train I got:

```
TypeError: 'SVC' object is not callable
```

Edit:

Here is the create_model function which takes the training variables and other model keywords as parameters:

```py
def create_model(X_train, y_train, model, **kwargs):
    created_model = model(**kwargs)
    created_model.fit(X_train,y_train)
    
    return created_model
```

Also here is the progress bar after trying recommended answer:
[progress bar screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxo7r.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need to pass your model's `predict` method, not the model on its own.

Second, (at least on my setup) `Explainer` cannot automatically determine a suitable explainer for `SVC`, so you might want to call an appropriate explainer directly, e.g. `KernelExplainer`:

```
explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(model.predict)
```

Comment: How do you know what `model` object is without seeing what `create_model` is?

Comment: It's right in the error message given in the question: Model: SVC(C=300, probability=True). I also set up an SVC model with the same parameters to bypass ambiguity of `create_model` function and arrived at the same error given the rest of the provided code.

Comment: I have tried this method but I got stuck for hours in the progress bar. I will edit the question to add the create_model function and the progress bar.

Comment: `KernelExplainer` will do computations for every row, so if your dataset is large there's not much you can do